# How to put circumflex accent in right position, math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I would like to put a circumflex accent over the letter j when I am in math mode.
I was supposed to use `$\hat{j}$` but the accent is not exactly over the dot: that is really unpleasant.

What do I have to do to adjust it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you really want to keep the dot above the `j` letter. Try `\hat{\jmath}` rather

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it also posible to obtain a similar result keeping the dot?

Comment: Please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question. A MWE is almost ever useful and sometimes essential. For this question best answer may depend on the font you are using and even the TeX format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With plain TeX you can use `\skew`, but the amount of skewing has to be determined case by case. Happily, once the amount has been found it can be made part of a definition.

```
$\hat{j}$ (normal)

$\skew{4.5}\hat{j}$ (with skew)

\bye
```

[image]

so a definition could be

```
\def\hatj{\skew{4.5}\hat{j}}
```

It also works with LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\hat{j}$ (normal)

$\skew{4.5}\hat{j}$ (with skew)

\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same. In this case it's better doing

```
\newcommand{\hatj}{\skew{4.5}\hat{j}}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you explicitly need j with dot plus hat then define

```
\def\hatj{\,\hat{\!j}}
```

and use `\hatj` in your document. The reason of this problem is that Knuth did not set the kerning pairs i-skew, j-skew in TeX font metric of cmmi10 font because he probably assumed that these dotted characters will never used with another math accents. The dot-less variants are available.

Note, that "skew" mentioned above is so called "skew character" (charcode 127 in cmmi10). Kerning with skew character controls the horizontal positions of math accents.

Comment: I would add `\ensuremath` to the definition, so it would automatically switch to math mode if needed. Nevertheless: Good answer, up-voted.

Comment: `\ensuremath` is LaTeX specific. I am not using LaTeX specific things because there are people (like me) not using LaTeX.